# Can't print order._id in the order page in MERN stack with redux project

Tags: javascript, mongodb, redux, mern

I am learning MERN stack with Redux and I got into the problems as I tried to print the order._id in the order page I couldn't do it. I am not sure what is missing here that causes problems. I couldn't print anything that is related to the current Order. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code below;

```
Order.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: 'User',
    },
    orderItems: [
      {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
        image: { type: String, required: true },
        price: { type: Number, required: true },
        product: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          required: true,
          ref: 'Product',
        },
      },
    ],
    shippingInfo: {
      address: { type: String, required: true },
      city: { type: String, required: true },
      postalCode: { type: String, required: true },
      country: { type: String, required: true },
    },
    paymentMethod: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    paymentResult: {
      id: { type: String },
      status: { type: String },
      update_time: { type: String },
      email_address: { type: String },
    },
    taxPrice: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0.0,
    },
    shippingPrice: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0.0,
    },
    totalPrice: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0.0,
    },
    isPaid: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
    paidAt: {
      type: Date,
    },
    isDelivered: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
    deliveredAt: {
      type: Date,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)


module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema)


OrderController.js
// Get single order   =>   /api/order/:id
exports.getSingleOrder = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
    
        const order = await Order.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).populate('user', 'firstName email')
        console.log(req.params.id)
           
        if (!order) {
            return next(new ErrorHandler('No Order found with this ID', 404))
        }


        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            order
        })
          
})


**OrderActions.js**
    // get ordetails for a single order by order/:id
export const getOrderDetails = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
         
        dispatch({ type: GET_ORDER_REQUEST });

          
        const  { data } = await axios.get(`/api/order/${id}`)


        dispatch({
            type: GET_ORDER_SUCCESS,
            payload: data,
        })

       } catch (error) {
          dispatch({
              type: GET_ORDER_FAIL,
              payload: error.response.data.message
          })
    }
}

orderReducers.js
export const orderDetailsReducer = ( state = { loading: true, orderItems: [], shippingAddress: {} },action) => {
        switch (action.type) {

          case GET_ORDER_REQUEST:
            return {
              ...state,
              loading: true,
            };

          case GET_ORDER_SUCCESS:
            return {
              loading: false,
              order: action.payload,
            
            };
          case GET_ORDER_FAIL:
            return {
              loading: false,
              error: action.payload,
            };
      
          default:
            return state;
        }
      };
    
      export const orderPayReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
          case ORDER_PAY_REQUEST:
            return {
              loading: true,
            };
          case ORDER_PAY_SUCCESS:
            return {
              loading: false,
              success: true,
            };
          case ORDER_PAY_FAIL:
            return {
              loading:false,
              error: action.payload,
            };
          case ORDER_PAY_RESET:
            return {};
            default:
                return state;
        }
      };


**Order.js**

import React, {Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import MetaData from '../MetaData';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { PayPalButton } from 'react-paypal-button-v2'
import axios from 'axios';
import { getOrderDetails, payOrder, deliverOrder } from '../actions/OrderActions';
import { ORDER_PAY_RESET } from '../constants/OrderConstants';

const Order = ({ match, history }) => {

    const orderId = match.params.id
    const [sdkReady, setSdkReady ] = useState(false)

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { user } = useSelector(state => state.auth)

    const orderDetails = useSelector(state => state.orderDetails)
    const { order, loading, error } = orderDetails

    console.log("This is order details for orderpage destructering :",order);
    const orderPay = useSelector((state) => state.orderPay)
    const { loading: loadingPay, success: successPay } = orderPay

    const orderDeliver = useSelector((state) => state.orderDeliver)
    const { loading: loadingDeliver, success: successDeliver} = orderDeliver


      useEffect(() => {
        if(!user) {
            history.push('/login');
        }
        
    const addPayPalScript = async () => {
        const { data: clientId } = await axios.get('/api/config/paypal')
        const script = document.createElement('script')
        script.type = 'text/javascript'
        script.src = `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=${clientId}`
        script.async = true
        script.onload = () => {
          setSdkReady(true)
        }
        document.body.appendChild(script)
      }
  
      if (!order || successPay || successDeliver || order._id !== orderId) {
        dispatch({ type: ORDER_PAY_RESET })
        //dispatch({ type: ORDER_DELIVER_RESET })
        dispatch(getOrderDetails(orderId))
      } else if (!order.isPaid) {
        if (!window.paypal) {
          addPayPalScript()
        } else {
          setSdkReady(true)
        }
      }
    }, [dispatch, orderId, successPay, successDeliver, order])
  
    
        
        
    const successPaymentHandler = (paymentResult) => {
        console.log(paymentResult)
        dispatch(payOrder(orderId, paymentResult))
    }

    const deliverHandler = () => {
        dispatch(deliverOrder(order._id));
      };
  

    
    return (

        <div className="container">
          <MetaData title={'Confirm Order'} />

                
                    <div className="row d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <div className="col-12 col-lg-8 mt-5 order-details">

                            <h1 className="my-5">Order # ${order._id}</h1>
                            {order.user.firstName}
                            <h4 className="mb-4">Shipping Info</h4>
                            <p><b>Name:</b> {user && user.name}</p>
                            {/* <p><b>Phone:</b> {shippingInfo && shippingInfo.phoneNo}</p>
                            <p className="mb-4"><b>Address:</b>{shippingDetails}</p>
                            <p><b>Amount:</b> ${totalPrice}</p> */}

                      <hr />
                      
                      <h4 className="mb-3">PAYMENT METHOD</h4>
                      <strong> Method:</strong>

                      <h4 className="mt-4">ORDER ITEMS</h4>

        
                          <Fragment>
                              <hr />
                              <div className="cart-item my-1" >
                                  <div className="row">
                                      <div className="col-4 col-lg-2">
                                          <img src="" alt="Laptop" height="45" width="65" />
                                      </div>

                                      <div className="col-5 col-lg-6">
                                          {/* <Link to={`/product/${item.product}`}></Link> */}
                                      </div>


                                      <div className="col-4 col-lg-4 mt-4 mt-lg-0">
                                          <p></p>
                                      </div>
                                      
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <hr />
                          </Fragment>
                      



                  </div>

                  <div className="col-12 col-lg-3 my-4">
                      <div id="order_summary">
                          <h4>Order Summary</h4>
                          <hr />
                          <p>Items: <span className="order-summary-values"></span></p>
                          <p>Shipping: <span className="order-summary-values"></span></p>
                          <p>Tax:  <span className="order-summary-values"></span></p>

                          <hr />

                          <p>Total: <span className="order-summary-values"></span></p>

                          <hr />
                          <button id="checkout_btn" className="btn btn-primary btn-block" onClick={successPaymentHandler}>Place Order</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>


              </div> 

          
        
        </div>
             
  )


     
  
}

export default Order
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I solved this problem by doing {orderId} instead of ${order._id} thanks

Answer (score 0):

Their is problem in your reducer and react component
In orderReducer.js

```
case GET_ORDER_SUCCESS:
   return{
   ...state,
   loading: false,
   orderItems: action.payload // in reducer initial state youe define orderItems      
   not order
}
```

in your react components use

```
const {orderItems, loading, error} = orderDetails //same as in reducer you define orderItems not order
```

and where you want to access orderItems details like _id, name and other things
use index based orderItems like
`const order_id = orderItems[0]._id`

hope this this will resolve your problem

Comment: In my case, I passed order{} empty object to the reducer and sorted it out. If I do your way I still got error_id undefined because here I am trying to print one single order Id with order items that are stored in an order object